# Changing from one-to-many to many-to-many throwing error Unacceptable type, Coredata, Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

A<<-->B

I had a one-to-many relationship in my app that was adding things to coredata, just fine.

But I switch to:

A<<-->>B

Still using the following code,

`[A setValue:myValue forKey:@"aRelationshipToB"];`

throws the error.

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "RowersBoat"; desired type = NSSet;

I'm sure that I'm just missing something or just lack the knowledge about coredata, could anyone give me some direction here, or maybe write out just a bit of code. That would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because many-to-many relationship requires set of objects (NSSet). Use this code instead:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithObjects:myValue,nil];
[A setValue:mySet forKey:@"aRelationshipToB"];
```